# Adobe AIR, Flex 4 - ContextMenu on right click not showing

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I'm pretty sure my code is OK as the Context Menu shows nicely when I compile for web, but when I compile for AIR nothing shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some code to make it easier for us to help you?

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured it out. In AIR you have to call ContextMenu.display() explicitly. For example on DataGrid.rightClick. Then use event.stageX and event.stageY to position it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Tip: You should put your solution in an answer to your question and mark it solved.  That makes it easier for others to search for it and it also allows us to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. In AIR you have to call ContextMenu.display() explicitly. For example on DataGrid.rightClick. Then use event.stageX and event.stageY to position it.